# Use prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, pid,0,0,0) to allow getting fd

Tags: c, linux, pid, file-descriptor, ptrace

I've been using sendmsg/recvmsg and the cmsg ancillary data to send a fd from one process to another (see man cmsg). Now since some time there is another way to do this:

https://copyconstruct.medium.com/seamless-file-descriptor-transfer-between-processes-with-pidfd-and-pidfd-getfd-816afcd19ed4

See also: man {pidfd_open, pidfd_getfd}

I found aout that a process can only get another process's fd under certain restrictions, otherwise a EPERM error occurs.
I've solved this by allowing the process (pida, which receives the fd) access to the process (pidb, having the fd to copy) with:

```
prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, pida, 0, 0, 0)
```

and now the process with pid pida can get the desired fd by:

```
fdtmp=syscall(SYS_pidfd_open, pidb, 0);
if (fdtmp>=0) {
   fda=syscall(SYS_pidfd_getfd, fdtmp, fdb, 0);
   close(fdtmp);
}
```

Now fda is a filedescriptor pointing to the same socket.

This works, but I think this way I am giving the process pida too much privileges (using the named prctl command). Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

[The commit message](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8649c322f75c96e7ced2fec201e123b2b073bf09) of the commit that added the `pidfd_getfd()` syscall to the kernel explains that it is mainly intended for things like fancy seccomp sandboxes:

> One reason to use this is to allow sandboxers to take actions on file
> descriptors on the behalf of another process.

More generally, it is intended for scenarios where the target process is not voluntarily/explicitly giving its file descriptor away - it is intended for situations where a somewhat privileged process wants to inspect/modify another uncooperative process.

If you are designing a program that wants to explicitly share file descriptors with another process, you should probably use one of these facilities that are designed for that purpose:

- As you wrote, unix domain sockets with ancillary messages are the standard way to do this.
- The "binder" subsystem can also do this, but that is mostly only used for Android, and Linux distributions usually don't enable it, so you probably don't want to use this.
- You can also create Linux processes such that they share *all* their file descriptors from the start, using [`clone()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) with `CLONE_FILES`. It's a neat feature in some situations, but it's also a bit weird and not used much.